# iPhone How to determine which orientations the previous view controller supports

Tags: iphone, sdk, orientation, uialertview

Since the built-in iOS UIAlertView doesn't give us the ability for skinning, I've built my own UIAlertViewCustom class, which I'm using instead.  Any of my view controller can display an instance of UIAlertViewCustom in the same that UIAlertView would be used, except my version allows for skinning graphics/fonts/colors, etc.

My UIAlertViewCustom class works by creating a new key window and root view controller.  I then draw my message view on this new root view controller.  (The view controller that chose to display the message is seen in the background just like you'd see with UIAlertView.

All of this is working perfectly.  There is one piece of functionality that I'd like to implement but haven't figured out how to.  I'd like each instance of UIAlertViewCustom to know whether or not it should auto-rotate when the device orientation changes.  Of course, I want to know which orientations the view controller beneath (the view controller that created the instance of UIAlertViewCustom and displayed it) supports?  If it supports portrait only, then I will not auto-rotate the UIAlertViewCustom, etc.

I don't want each view controller to have to pass in a supported orientation property to each instance of UIAlertViewCustom.  I would just like each instance of UIAlertViewCustom to be able to figure out if it should auto-rotate or not.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this in your view controller class:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return [[view superview] shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}
```

I'm not sure if it's going to work, but that is where I would start. This is necessary because the default implementation for this returns `YES` for `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` and everything else is `NO`.

Another small thing. Apple has reserved the prefixes that it uses (NS, CF, CA, UI, etc...) and your custom classes shouldn't use them.

**EDIT** Changed [self superview] to [view superview]

Comment: I tried this but, the compiler is telling me that [self superview] is invalid in this context.

Comment: I saw that mistake before I posted, but forgot to correct it. A UIView Controller is not a view.

Comment: I came up with a solution that seems to work perfectly.  My UIAlertViewCustom instance already had a delegate reference to the calling view controller.  So, I was able to use that to determine what orientations that calling view controller supported.  I can't answer my own questions yet, so I had to place the ansewr here as a comment.  Also, thanks for the head's up on the UI prefix.